# Java Crosstab - preparedstatement query

Tags: java, postgresql, pivot-table, prepared-statement

I have a typical crosstab query with static parameters. It works fine with `createStatement`. I want to use `preparestatement` to query instead.

```java
String query = "SELECT * FROM crosstab(
    'SELECT rowid, a_name, value 
    FROM test WHERE a_name = ''att2'' 
                OR a_name = ''att3''
    ORDER BY 1,2'
) AS ct(row_name text, category_1 text, category_2 text, category_3 text);";
PreparedStatement stat = conn.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet rs = stat.getResultSet();

stat.executeQuery(query);
rs = stat.getResultSet();

while (rs.next()) {
    //TODO
}
```

But it does not seem to work.

I get a `PSQLException` -

> Can't use query methods that take a query string on a `PreparedStatement`.

Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have fallen for the confusing type hierarchy of `PreparedStatement extends Statement`:

`PreparedStatement` has the same `execute*(String)` methods like `Statement`, but they're not supposed to be used, just use the **parameterless** `execute*()` methods of `PreparedStatement` --- you already have given the actual query string to execute using `conn.prepareStatement()`.

Answer (score 7):

Please try:

```java
String query = "...";
PreparedStatement stat = conn.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    // TODO
}
```