# Insert different datatypes into postgreSQL in a query error

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I want to insert a record into PostgreSQL database. Most of it's fields are String, but there is also java.sql.date, and BIGINT. How can i do that? My code doesn't seem to work.

```
    public Record(RecordFields data)
    {
        CreateNewRecord(data);
    }

        private void CreateNewRecord(RecordFields recordFields)
        {
            try
            {    

                    String addRecord = "INSERT INTO " + GlobalFields.TABLE + " VALUES (? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?);";

                    Connection conn = DataBase.Connect();

                    PreparedStatement query = conn.prepareStatement(addRecord);
                    query.setLong(1, recordFieldsID);
                    query.setString(2, recordFields.surname);
                    query.setString(3, recordFields.name);
                    query.setString(4, recordFields.sex);

                    DateTime date = recordFields.bornDate.toDateTime();
                    query.setTimestamp(5, new Timestamp(date.getMillis()));

                    query.setString(6, recordFields.adress);
                    query.setString(7, recordFields.contact);
                    query.setString(8, recordFields.insurance);
                    query.setString(9, recordFields.commentary);

                    query.executeUpdate(addRecord);
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

table generator:

```
public static void CreateTable()
    {
        try
        {
            Connection conn = DataBase.Connect();

            try
            {
                Statement stat = conn.createStatement();

                String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + GlobalFields.TABLE 
                    + "(id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,"
                    + "surname TEXT,"
                    + "name TEXT,"
                    + "sex CHAR(1),"                 
                    + "bornDate DATE,"
                    + "adress TEXT,"
                    + "contact TEXT,"
                    + "insurance TEXT,"
                    + "commentary TEXT);";

                stat.executeUpdate(createTable);
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.close();
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
```

public class RecordFields 
{
    public RecordFields()
    {
    }

```
public long id;
public String surname;
public String name;
public String sex;
public MutableDateTime bornDate;
public String adress;
public String contact;
public String insurance;
public String commentary;
```

}

Comment: Perhaps you could describe how it doesn't work. What is the output? Is an exception being thrown? What are the particulars?

Comment: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't use query methods that take a query string on a PreparedStatement.
 at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:294)
 at EngineClasses.Record.CreateNewRecord(Pacjent.java:62)
 at EngineClasses.Record.<init>(Record.java:37)
 at mainPackage.Test.main(Test.java:38)

Comment: I've found this http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-jdbc/2004-11/msg00201.php but now i have no idea how to insert all of my data into database.

Comment: @Noran  The link is 2004

Comment: @AmitD but that link's diagnose (not the solution) is spot on nevertheless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
stat.executeUpdate(createTable);
```

is the culprit.  On PreparedStatements [executeUpdate takes no parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29).

So, modify that line to - just [as expained by Tom Anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12182875/112079)

```
stat.executeUpdate();
```

and you're done

Also,

```
INSERT table VALUES (values)
```

makes your code unnecessarily brittle.  Use

```
INSERT INTO table (fieldlist) VALUES (valuelist)
```

instead.

And also 2:

```
DateTime date = recordFields.bornDate.toDateTime();
query.setTimestamp(5, new Timestamp(data.getMillis()));
```

is a rather convoluted version of saying

```
query.setTimestamp(5,new Timestamp(recordFields.bornDate.getMillis()));
```

EDIT: regarding [Date in postgressql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182751/date-in-postgressql)

What Tom says is that to fill a PostgreSQL `DATE` type column you can either use a `java.sql.date` type variable (as opposed to the "common" `java.util.Date`), or a `javax.sql.TimeStamp`.  But that's totally unrelated to the present problem ( which is caused by the parameter in the call to executeUpdate ) and what you do here (set it using a Timestamp type variable) is OK.

Comment: What method should i use, to send that kind of query with parameters?

Comment: Also please take a look on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182751/date-in-postgressql and explaint to me Tom Anderson's answer, because looks like i dont understand something.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776779/java-crosstab-preparedstatement-query) question.

Essentially, your code should have the following form:

```
String query = "..."; 
PreparedStatement stat = conn.prepareStatement(query); 
ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(); 
while (rs.next()) { 
  // TODO 
}
```

Because you haven't included all the source code of the problematic method, it's difficult to diagnose completely.