# Can you tell me why I get "Can't use query methods that take a query string on a PreparedStatement."?

Tags: java, postgresql, prepared-statement

I keep hitting an error "Can't use query methods that take a query string on a PreparedStatement." when trying to debug the following code & SQL Select query. (Postgres 9.4, jdk 1.8)  Maybe I'm blind and it's a simple type, but I could use some help.

My Console Ouput:

> SELECT rowid, firstname, lastname, prefname, email1, email2, email3, type, status, preflang, mbrappid, deviceid, mbrstatus, mbrtype, mbrcat, pr_phonevoice FROM qbirt.person WHERE pr_sms = 47 ORDER BY lastupdt DESC
>
> E R R O R 
>   JDBC Prep'd Stmt error on Primary Phone FKey...
>   Phone FKey: 47
>
> SQLException: Can't use query methods that take a query string on a PreparedStatement. 
>   SQLState: 42809 
>   VendorError: 0 
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't use query methods that take a query string on a PreparedStatement.
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:102) at solutions.demand.qbirt.Person.findMember(Person.java:762)`

Portion of code:

```
            if (!foundMbr && foundPhoneID > 0) {
                if (QbirtUtils.verbose) {
                    System.out.println("Querying Person by FK ID for phones: " + foundPhoneID + "\n");
                }

                if (mode.equals(pMode.SMS)) {
                    qry = "SELECT rowid, firstname, lastname, prefname, email1, email2, email3, type, "
                            + "status, preflang, mbrappid, deviceid, mbrstatus, mbrtype, mbrcat, pr_phonevoice "
                            + "FROM qbirt.person "
                            + "WHERE pr_sms = ? "
                            + "ORDER BY lastupdt DESC;";
                } else {
                    if (mode.equals(pMode.VOICE)) {
                        qry = "SELECT rowid, firstname, lastname, prefname, email1, email2, email3, type, "
                                + "status, preflang, mbrappid, deviceid, mbrstatus, mbrtype, mbrcat, pr_phonevoice "
                                + "FROM qbirt.person "
                                + "WHERE pr_phonevoice = ? "
                                + "ORDER BY lastupdt DESC;";
                    } else { 
                        if (mode.equals(pMode.PHONE)) {
                            qry = "SELECT DISTINCT ON (rowid) rowid, firstname, lastname, prefname, email1, email2, email3, type, "
                                    + "status, preflang, mbrappid, deviceid, mbrstatus, mbrtype, mbrcat, pr_phonevoice "
                                    + "FROM qbirt.person "
                                    + "WHERE (pr_sms = ? OR pr_phonevoice = ?) "
                                    + "ORDER BY lastupdt DESC, rowid DESC;";
                        }
                    }
                }



                try {
                    PreparedStatement pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(qry);
                    pStmt.setInt(1, foundPhoneID);
                    if (mode.equals(pMode.PHONE)) {
                        pStmt.setInt(2, foundPhoneID);
                    }
                    System.out.println(pStmt.toString());
                    ResultSet rs = pStmt.executeQuery(qry);   <-------
```

I have confirmed that the fields contain the following values:
`foundMbr` = false, `foundPhoneID` = 47, `mode` = SMS, and that  `qry = "SELECT rowid, firstname, lastname, prefname, email1, email2, email3, type, status, preflang, mbrappid, deviceid, mbrstatus, mbrtype, mbrcat, pr_phonevoice FROM qbirt.person WHERE pr_sms = ? ORDER BY lastupdt DESC;";`

I get the error on the line:  `ResultSet rs = pStmt.executeQuery(qry);`

As you can see in the console, I have even confirmed that the pStmt is holding the correct binding because I print it out.  - That said, it seems to be missing the ending ';'.  Not sure why that is because I can see it in the qry string.  I assume that is just a quirk of the preparedStatment.

I have also copied this exact SQL into pgAdmin III and successfully executed it manually.   Although, I did have to add back the ';'.  I use virtually this same code in many other areas without problem.

Could it be that the missing ';'?
Maybe some sort of type mismatch?  (foundPhoneID is an int., rowid is a serial/integer, pr_sms is an integer FKey)
Could it be the block of if statements that defines the qry string?

TIA!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try doing:

```
pStmt.executeQuery()
```

instead of

```
pStmt.executeQuery(qry)
```

as discussed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776779/java-crosstab-preparedstatement-query)

Comment: Bloody hell. Thanks. (And sorry for the dupe!)